# I've made a correct Procfile but I dont see a worker dyno in the dashboard

Tags: node.js, heroku, worker, procfile

Im trying to deploy a very simple bot to heroku but I cant set the worker dyno because it doesnt show up on the dashboard, even though I have a Procfile with just one line it: worker: node app.js

Comment: Was your build successful? Do you see your app's code when you run `heroku run bash`?

Comment: @DamienMATHIEU When I run heroku run bash it executes without errors, it doesnt print anything it just gives me the bash prompt to type. On 'ls' I see every file/folder except the Procfile, should it be invisible or is this the problem?

Comment: If the Procfile isn't there, it means you haven't committed. It may be in gitignore, or you didn't commit the change.

Comment: @DamienMATHIEU I did `git add .` - `git commit -m "Heroku stuff"` - `git push heroku master` and it just tells me everything is up to date. It does this everytime actually, so you might be right, but not because I forgot, rather because for some reason its not detecting any changes whatsoever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was that Heroku only builds off the master branch and I was developing on a different branch. I solved this by assigning my current branch as the master branch `git push heroku YourDifferentBranchHere:master`

Answer (score 10):

Same issue, I resolved it from Heroku [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#scaling-a-process-type):

Scaling a process type
Heroku runs one `web` dyno for you automatically, but other process types don’t start by default. To launch a worker, you need to scale it up to one dyno:

```
heroku ps:scale worker=1
Scaling worker processes... done, now running 1
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, correct code but worker didn't appear. For me, the issue was that my Procfile was named "procfile" and not "Procfile"

Comment: Thanks for this. The guide I was following specifically said to name it `procfile` and I could not figure out why it wasn't being recognized.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was easily solved for me once I changed the `procfile` name to `Procfile`.
After this I wrote the following code:

```
worker: node bot.js
$ heroku ps:scale web=1 worker=5
heroku ps:scale web=1 worker=5
```

Then I refreshed the page, it worked perfectly for me.